# AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio bug? AWS C# lambda failed to load the librdkafka native library of Kafka?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, confluent-platform

The following .Net core 2.1 lambda application with nuget package of `Confluent.Kafka` is created in Visual Studio with AWS toolkit for Visual Studio 2017. However, the following code

```
using (var producer = new Producer<Null, string>(config, null, new StringSerializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
{
    await producer.ProduceAsync("mytopic", null, msg);
}
```

got the following error in CloudWatch

```
One or more errors occurred. (Failed to load the librdkafka native library.): AggregateException
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )

at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.LibRdKafka.Initialize(String userSpecifiedPath)
at Confluent.Kafka.Producer..ctor(IEnumerable`1 config, Boolean manualPoll, Boolean disableDeliveryReports)
at Confluent.Kafka.Producer`2..ctor(IEnumerable`1 config, ISerializer`1 keySerializer, ISerializer`1 valueSerializer, Boolean manualPoll, Boolean disableDeliveryReports)
at StratsLambda.Function.FunctionHandler(S3Event evnt, ILambdaContext context) in C:\work\.....
```

Here is the AWS toolkit publishing messages:

```
Executing publish command
Deleted previous publish folder
... invoking 'dotnet publish', working folder 'C:\work\....\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish'
... publish: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.179.6572 for .NET Core
... publish: Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
... publish:   Restore completed in 31.3 ms for C:\work\....\StratsLambda.csproj.
... publish:   Restore completed in 62.87 ms for C:\work\....\StratsLambda.csproj.
... publish:   StratsLambda -> C:\work\....\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\linux-x64\StratsLambda.dll
... publish:   StratsLambda -> C:\work\....\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish\
Zipping publish folder C:\work\....\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\publish to C:\work\....\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\StratsLambda.zip
... zipping: Amazon.Lambda.Core.dll
... zipping: Amazon.Lambda.S3Events.dll
... zipping: Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.dll
... zipping: AWSSDK.CloudWatchLogs.dll
... zipping: AWSSDK.Core.dll
... zipping: AWSSDK.S3.dll
... zipping: Confluent.Kafka.dll
... zipping: debian9-librdkafka.so
... zipping: librdkafka.so
... zipping: Newtonsoft.Json.dll
... zipping: Serilog.dll
... zipping: Serilog.Sinks.AwsCloudWatch.dll
... zipping: Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.dll
... zipping: StratsLambda.deps.json
... zipping: StratsLambda.dll
... zipping: StratsLambda.pdb
... zipping: StratsLambda.runtimeconfig.json
... zipping: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
Updating code for existing function savstrats
Config settings saved to C:\work\....\aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json
```

I created a unit test function to test the Kafka producing and it can send message to my Kafka successfully. And the folder `...\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1` has only the following files.

```
Name                                Length
----                                ------
StratsLambda.deps.json               58489
StratsLambda.dll                     12800
StratsLambda.pdb                      1908
StratsLambda.runtimeconfig.dev.json    238
StratsLambda.runtimeconfig.json        154
```

---

**Update:**
The file StratsLambda.deps.json has the following section,

```
  "librdkafka.redist/0.11.5": {
    "native": {
      "runtimes/linux-x64/native/centos7-librdkafka.so": {
        "fileVersion": "0.0.0.0"
      },
      "runtimes/linux-x64/native/debian9-librdkafka.so": {
        "fileVersion": "0.0.0.0"
      },
      "runtimes/linux-x64/native/librdkafka.so": {
        "fileVersion": "0.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
```

I also tried to create the folder `runtimes/linux-x64/native` and movied files to it in the zip file.

However, I still got the error of

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyApp.deps.json) was not found:
>
> package: 'librdkafka.redist', version: '0.11.5'
>
> path: 'runtimes/linux-x64/native/centos7-librdkafka.so'
>
> START RequestId: 73e39d0b-8ec8-11e8-8597-.... Version: $LATEST
>
> Failed to execute the Lambda function. The dotnet CLI failed to start with the provided deployment package. Please check CloudWatch logs for this Lambda function to get detailed information about this failure.: LambdaException

Comment: Not being a .net person, how can you mix Unix shared libraries (`.so` files) with Windows shared libraries (`.dll`)?

Comment: Right. I updated the question at the bottom. I created a unit test and the Kafka code works fine called by the test code.

Comment: Maybe the aws lambda C# is using Linux version of .Net core?

Answer (score 0):

As it mentioned its because of those libraries are part of runtime only and require specific runtime to be available on the host computer.

I would suggest to refrain from including runtime directories in your source, it may work but it would look ugly.

I used following solution.

Added `<GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>` tag in project file. Example below;

[image: example]

Alternatively, you can also add `-p:GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles=true` as a parameter to `dotnet publish` command on your build server.

Above should output `runtime` directory in you `bin` (or output) directory.
if you are using nuget to build a package and then you will also need to ensure your `*.nuspec` (if this is what being used for packaging) also includes directories in nuget package. Example below includes all files and all directories in the package.

[image: Example]